# PHP String To Integer Casting

Tags: php, string, casting, integer

```
$x = '37965190010';

$y = (int) $x;

var_dump($x);

var_dump($y);
```

The above will output

```
string '37965190010'
int 2147483647
```

Why does the casting not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the highest number in an `int` (for 32bits) cannot exceed `2147483647`, you can check it by outputting the constant `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) in order to find out more.

Comment: Ah I see, many thanks!